# "daily work" vs. "daily labour"

Tags: grammar

Is the description for a video grammatically correct:

> Deep insights into our daily labour as chemists: Have fun!

I didn't find the expression *daily labour* in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/).

Is it better to write:

> Deep insights into our daily work as chemists ;-7 Have fun!"

;-7 declares the irony.

Answer (score 2):

As a sentence fragment, omitting the expected introductory clause "This is a video which shows", it's grammatical. There's nothing about "daily labour" which is any different grammatically to "daily work".

*Labour* connotes expending far more effort than simple *work,* so the collocation is intended to be mildly amusing. *Daily labour* [doesn't occur in print very often](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=daily+labour), but it might bring to mind something like...

[image: Prisoners breaking rocks]

... a chain gang.

The use of *daily labour* when the work as a chemist is nothing like as hard as **that** is ironic, and doesn't need to be marked with emoticons, even if the source of the quote is a place where emoticons would not be out of place.

Emoticons don't reduce the emotion they indicate: they indicate that that emotion is **intended.** So using it in the way your [edited question suggests](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/216035/revisions) is not feasible. Using *daily work* already doesn't have the irony that *daily labour* has. There might be a case for retaining it to make clear that a statement is deliberately ironic; there's no case for using it where a statement is not ironic at all.

[Image: [I am a Fugitive from a Chain Gang](http://www.imdb.com/media/rm3026491392/tt0023042?ref_=tt_pv_md_2) (Warner Bros, 1932) via [Peak Oil](http://peak-oil.livejournal.com/932688.html)]